# What is the name of Peggy's husband in Captain America: The Winter Soldier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

I'm having a hard time hearing the name of Peggy's husband she names. I'm not the greatest at spelling but it sounds like his name is something like: Emanhu Winter?

Here's the scene if anyone can help, he's named at 1:40:

Answer (score 5):

She doesn't give a specific name. The phrase she utters at 1:40 is:

> He saved over 1000 men, including *the man who, would ahh,* who would become my husband, as it turned out

which I guess you hear as *Emanhu Winter*, because of the slight hesitation and repetition there in the line delivery.

Comment: "He saved over 1000 men, including Emanhu Winter, who would become my husband as it turns out" assuming my spelling is correct.

What does she say between "including" and "who would become my husband"?

Comment: @yarpyarp She pauses and repeats herself. “He saved over 1,000 men. Including the man who would... who would become my husband.”

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the slight hesitation the actor uses, rather than the tidied version. I think that is the source of the extra syllables you're filling in.

Comment: This much is clear for what she says: "He saved over 1000 men, including ____ who would become my husband as it turned out" There is not a stutter I know that much.

Comment: For me and for @MikeScott at least, it is very clear. Give it an hour and come back to it with fresh ears. 

Comment: @yarpyarp Are you a native speaker of English received pronunciation (the middle to upper class accent of southern England)? I am, and I assure you that what she says is quite clear if your ear is tuned for that specific accent.

Comment: Ah, so she says "the man who would a, who would become my husband as it turns out" Thanks Michael MacAskill! Upvoted

Comment: More of an "uh" than an "a" but still basically the right answer

Comment: @valorum I'm a New Zealand English speaker, we treat vowels differently down here… 

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill - However you and your colonial chums choose to butcher the English language is entirely up to you, but it's still an "uh".

Comment: Agree to disagree. I view "uh" as a word generally accompanied by a question mark. We're a bit closer to the Queen's English than you former colonials, and that is what the character is speaking…

Comment: To my ear it's "the man who would, er, who would, become my husband." I am a native Southern British speaker. Perhaps that's why Yarpyarp hears an "E" sound at the start.